# I need to get the expected output? How do i improve my function ? New to C community?

Tags: arrays, c, function, command-line

Basically , I am trying to read a text file and store  its content to check the balance of the different bracket-type pairs on command-line. But I keep on getting the same output.

The code is intended to detect the following error cases:

1. The most recent closed bracket does not match the most recent open bracket.
2. A closed bracket is encountered when there is no open bracket to be matched.
3. The end of the source code is reached when there is at least one open brackets to be matched.

Main function :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main (int argc , char* argv[])
    {
        char *txt = malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
    
        readfile (argv[1] , txt) ;        
        brcheck(txt);
        free(txt);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Read Function :

```
    char *readfile (char *s1 , char *t) 
    { 
        FILE *f;
        int c; 

        int length = 0;
            
        f = fopen(s1 , "r");
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error opening file.txt");  
        }
        else 
        {
            do 
            {
                c = fgetc(f);
                txt[length]=c;
                length++;
            } while (c != EOF && c != '\0');
        }
        
        fclose(f);
        return txt;
    }
```

Bracket Function :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    
    char stack[50];
    int top = -1;
    
    void brcheck(char *c)
    {
        int i= 0;
        
        while (c[i] != EOF)
        {
            printf("%c" , c[i]);
            
            if (c[i] == '{')
            {
                stack[++top] = c[i];
                
                if (stack[i] != '}')
                {
                    printf("\n'}' expected\n");
                }
                else if (stack[i] == '}')
                {
                    top--;
                }
            }   
            else if (c[i] == '[')
            {
                stack[++top] = c[i];
                
                if (stack[i] != ']')
                {
                    printf("\n']' expected\n");
                }
                else if (stack[i] == ']')
                {
                    top--;
                }
            }   
            else if (c[i] == '(')
            {
                stack[++top] = c[i];
                
                if (stack[i] != ')')
                {
                    printf("\n')' expected\n");
                }
                else if (stack[i] == ')')
                {
                    top--;
                }
            }    
            else if (c[i] == ')')
            {
                if (stack[top] != '(')
                {
                    printf("\n'(' expected\n");
                }
                else if (stack[top] == '(')
                {
                    top--;
                }
            }
            else if (c[i] == ']')
            {
                if (stack[top] != '[')
                {
                    printf("\n'[' expected\n");
                }
                else if (stack[top] == '[')
                {
                    top--;
                }
            }
            else if (c[i] == '}')
            {
                if (stack[top] != '{')
                {
                    printf("\n'{' expected\n");
                }
                else if (stack[top] == '{')
                {
                top--;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    
        if (top-= -1)   
        {
            printf("’}’ expected before End of Code\n");
        }
        
    }
```

INPUT FILE : A text file to read file.txt

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(int argc , char**argv]


{

printf("this is my program\n");


return 0;

}
```

What output I am getting is this which is wrong it starts checking for every open  bracket but i actually want to check for (] this brackets since it is wrong  :

Actual Output :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(

')' expected

)

{

'}' expected

printf(

')' expected

"this is my program\n");


return 0;

}
```

Expected output:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(int argc , char**argv]

                             ')' expected

{

printf("this is my program\n");


return 0;

}
```

Comment: You didn't show `header.h`. And please format the question properly

Comment: It just includes the function prototype sir ? and format in what sense? @Jabberwocky

Comment: Read this: [mcve]

Comment: "Perfect" in what sense? Depending on the persons to read the source, there will be many different and contradicting forms of the very same program.

Comment: In which way is the output wrong? What is the correct output you expect?

Comment: I think what I have posted is required as without it you wont be able to run the function ? @Jabberwocky

Comment: Expected output is correct output @thebusybee That is what I want

Comment: Your code does not compile. [Edit] and add compilable code. Add each file in a different section, so we can copy/paste/compile/run your code. For example what is `txt`?

Comment: @FizzaHoseni : I think you misunderstand.  Include a _small_ example of an input file that exhibits the problems.  Show (as you have) the actual output, and _also_ the _expected_ output.  Simply saying you want the expected output is insufficient since we do not know what your expectations are.  Your description is not entirely clear.

Comment: I have rectified the mistake @Jabberwocky its actually chat tx where its store the content of  file.txt in a variable !

Comment: What kind of text is this intended to parse?  You appear to be testing it on C code, where `<...>` is not semantically a bracketing delimiter.  If you try to check those without encoding any C language specific grammar, you will run to problems with `>` and `<` operators which are not paired.  In the case of the preprocessor `#include` directive, the `<...>` delimiters are grammatically no different to `"..."` delimiters, and you are not checking for them, so why are you checking for `<...>`?

Comment: I have edited my code. You can see the actual output and expected output! @Clifford

Comment: You may also want to parse `"..."` in any case because in a string, to skip checking inside strings.  Similarly you would want to do the same with comment delimiters : `/*...*/` and `//...\n`. It gets complicated!

Comment: because I want to check the balance off diff brackets which includes three cases : 1.The most recent closed bracket does not match the most recent open bracket. 2. A closed bracket is encountered when there is no open bracket to be matched. 3. The end of the source code is reached when there is at least one open brackets to
be matched @Clifford I want to implement these cases in my bracket algorithm so I was trying all diff brackets

Comment: @FizzaHoseni Try to print out the values on the top of the stack for every iteration and check if it contains what you think it does.

Comment: i tried but i didn't get :') @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer

Comment: You may need to explain what "diff brackets" are?  In the context of the question and output, I have no idea what that might mean.  My point however stands in C code, `< >` are not brackets.  They are either operators or pre-processor `#include` file name delimiters.

Comment: diff brackets means - {} [] <> () - just trying to check the balance of these in my bracket algortihm and want to print an error for example if there is a wrong brackets like ( ] it should give error under ] bracket that ')' is to expected @Clifford

Comment: however if we leave <> these brackets as you said are you able to make improvements to my code according to expected ouput ! Lets leave these brackets then <> @Clifford

Comment: @FizzaHoseni : I understand all that - what I don't understand is the terminology.  Why "diff brackets".  And you are still wilfully ignoring the fact that `if( x > y)` is valid code and `>` and `<` are _not_ brackets - at least not in the context of the text file you are parsing.

Comment: Lets ignore <> angled brackets ! And focus on these three [] () {} @Clifford

Comment: I have removed the code for these <> ! Can we improve my code now @Clifford

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer can you help please if you understand my algorithm ?

Comment: You're using `i` to index into two unrelated (and different sized) arrays.

Comment: @FizzaHoseni : Wow - its only been up an hour give me a chance!  Working on it, but the question needed disambiguating regardless.

Comment: `txt` is a `char` array, but `EOF` is an `int` - you cannot _safely_ use EOF indicate the end of the text in `brcheck()` - you should write a NUL rather than `EOF` or pass the length to `brcheck()`.

Comment: @Clifford please take your time :)

Comment: I have mentioned 3 cases in my comment according to that it should be done @Clifford

Comment: The three rules you mention in the comments should be in the question - you won't get a complete answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char stack[50];
int top = -1;

char closer(char c){
    if (c == '(') return ')';
    else return c+2;
}

void brcheck(char *c)
{
    int i= 0;
    while (c[i] != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c" , c[i]);
    
         if (c[i] == '<'  )
        {
            stack[++top] = c[i];
        }
        
        else if (c[i] == '{')
        {
            stack[++top] = c[i];
        }   
        
        else if (c[i] == '[')
        {
            stack[++top] = c[i];
        }   
        
        else if (c[i] == '(')
        {
            stack[++top] = c[i];
        }  


        else if (c[i] == '>')
        {
            if (stack[top] != '<')
            {
                printf("\n'%c' expected\n",closer(stack[top]));
            }
            top--;
        }
            
        else if (c[i] == ')')
        {
            if (stack[top] != '(')
            {
                printf("\n'%c' expected\n",closer(stack[top]));
            }
            top--;
        }
        
        else if (c[i] == ']')
        {
            if (stack[top] != '[')
            {
                printf("\n'%c' expected\n",closer(stack[top]));
            }
            top--;
        }

        else if (c[i] == '}')
        {
            if (stack[top] != '{')
            {
                printf("\n'%c' expected\n",closer(stack[top]));
            }
            top--;
        }
        i++; 
    }

    if (top >= 0)   
    {
        printf("} expected before End of Code\n");
    }
    printf("%c",stack[top]);
}

char *readfile (char *s1 , char *t)
{
    FILE *f;
    int c; 
    int length = 0;
    f = fopen(s1 , "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file.txt");  
    }
    else 
    {
        do 
        {
            c = fgetc(f);
            t[length]=c;
            length++;
        } while (c != EOF && c != '\0');
    }
    fclose(f);
    return t;
}

int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    char *txt = malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
    readfile (argv[1] , txt) ;        
    brcheck(txt);
    free(txt);
    return 0;
}
```

You don't have to post each function separately here

Check your read function txt is undefined, it should be t probably

As for your logic, you don't need to check anything for opening brackets. Simply push them in the stack. When a closing bracket is encountered check if top of stack matches it else print what is expected ie the closing bracket for the top of stack. I have written a function (closer for that). Check ASCII values if you need more info on that

Comment: No I have to check for the opening brackets as well. For example when I am giving this in my text file   int main ))   it should say under  the first bracket that  '('  that opening bracket is expected @AaryaChaumal

Comment: its giving me error when I give int main )) in main it does not give me  anything? it should give me under the first bracket that '(' that opening bracket is expected

Comment: @FizzaHoseni - that is not what your question says or what the example output indicates.  The error is indicated under the erroneous closing bracket, not the opening bracket.

Comment: well I have to check for all the three cases !!  three cases : 1.The most recent closed bracket does not match the most recent open bracket. 2. A closed bracket is encountered when there is no open bracket to be matched. 3. The end of the source code is reached when there is at least one open brackets to be matched @Clifford

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea using a stack - but it is simpler if on an opening bracket, you push the corresponding expected *closing* bracket, then on a closing bracket, you pop of the stack and check that it matches the current character.

I would suggest approaching this first by encapsulating the stack and push/pop operations.  This need not be elaborate.  For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    char stack[128] ;
    int index ;
}  sCharStack ;

void push_char( sCharStack* stack, char data )
{
    if( stack->index < sizeof( stack->stack ) - 2 )
    {
        stack->index++ ;
        stack->stack[stack->index] = data ;
    }
}

int pop_char( sCharStack* stack )
{
    int pop = -1 ;
    if( stack->index > 0 )
    {
        pop = stack->stack[stack->index] ;
        stack->index-- ;
    }

    return pop ;
}
```

That makes the rest of the code clearer and less error prone.

Then I would suggest using a data structure containing bracket pairs, so that your `brcheck` function might have:

```
    static const struct
    {
        char open ;
        char close ;
    }  brackets[] = {{'{','}'},
                     {'[',']'},
                     {'(',')'} } ;
    static const int bracket_type_count = sizeof(brackets) / 
                                          sizeof(*brackets) ;

    sCharStack expected_stack = { {0},0 } ;
```

That way you avoid a lot of conditional code; you simply iterate through the pairings. You can even easily add new paired-delimiters by only modifying `brackets` array initialiser (so you can add the `<...>` you originally had (though that is problematic for C code).

The complete `brcheck()` might then be:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void brcheck( const char* text, int length )
{
    static const struct
    {
        char open ;
        char close ;
    }  brackets[] = {{'{','}'},
                     {'[',']'},
                     {'(',')'} } ;
    static const int bracket_type_count = sizeof(brackets) / 
                                          sizeof(*brackets) ;

    sCharStack expected_stack = { {0},0 } ;
    int curpos = 0 ;

    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        char current_char = text[i] ;

        // Maintain cursor position
        curpos = current_char == '\n' ? 0 : curpos + 1 ;

        // Ouput content
        printf( "%c", current_char ) ;

        // Check for open bracket...
        bool open = false ;
        for( int b = 0; !open && b < bracket_type_count; b++ )
        {
            if( current_char == brackets[b].open )
            {
                open = true ;

                // Push expected closing character
                push_char( &expected_stack, brackets[b].close ) ;
            }
        }

        // Check for close bracket
        bool close = false ;
        for( int b = 0; !close && b < bracket_type_count; b++ )
        {
            if( current_char == brackets[b].close )
            {
                close = true ;

                // Check for mismatch
                char expected_char = pop_char( &expected_stack ) ;
                if( expected_char != brackets[b].close )
                {
                    printf( "\n%*c\'%c\' expected\n", curpos - 2, ' ', expected_char ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Check for unterminated brackets
    if( expected_stack.index != 0 )
    {
        printf( "\n\'%c\' expected\n", (char)pop_char( &expected_stack) ) ;
    }
}
```

Note also the use of the `curpos` variable and the `%*c` `printf` format specifier to position the error message in the correct location as indicated in your example.

The following test code:

```c
int main()
{
    char* text = 
"#include <stdio.h>\n\
int main(int argc , char**argv]\n\
{\n\
    printf(\"this is my program\\n\");\n\
    return 0;\n\
}\n" ;

    brcheck( text, strlen( text ) ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Outputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc , char**argv]
                             ')' expected

{
    printf("this is my program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Changing the test text to:

```
    char* text = 
"#include <stdio.h>\n\
int main(int argc , char**argv]\n\
{\n\
    printf(\"this is my program\\n\"};\n\
    return 0;\n\
}\n" ;
```

results in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc , char**argv]
                             ')' expected

{
    printf("this is my program\n"}
                                ')' expected
;
    return 0;
}
```

See that the error message splits the line.  It is not clear from your example where the erroneous bracket is at the end of the line whether that is acceptable. It can be fixed, but it gets more complicated, and a line may have multiple mismatches.  I suggest in that case you create FIFO buffer of structures containing the expected bracket and the cursor position, then output the errors in FIFO order in separate lines after the a  is found and output in `text`.  So for example given:

```
    struct
    {
        char expected ;
        int curpos ;
    } errorlist[32] = {{0,0}} ;
    static const int errorlist_len = sizeof(errorlist) / 
                                      sizeof(*errorlist) ;
    int error_count = 0  ;
```

Instead of immediatly printing the error you'd have:

```
                    if( error_count < errorlist_len )
                    {
                        errorlist[error_count].expected = expected_char ;
                        errorlist[error_count].curpos = curpos ;
                        error_count++ ;
                    }
```

then after the close-delimiter check loop:

```
        // Print errors after newline
        if( current_char == '\n' )
        {
            for( int e = 0; e < error_count; e++ )
            {
                printf( "%*c\'%c\' expected\n", errorlist[e].curpos - 2, ' ',  errorlist[e].expected ) ;
            }
            error_count = 0 ;
        }
```

That solves both the split line issue and multiple errors on one line.

In full:

```
void brcheck( const char* text, int length )
{
    static const struct
    {
        char open ;
        char close ;
    }  brackets[] = {{'{','}'},
                     {'[',']'},
                     {'(',')'} } ;
    static const int bracket_type_count = sizeof(brackets) / 
                                          sizeof(*brackets) ;

    struct
    {
        char expected ;
        int curpos ;
    } errorlist[32] = {{0,0}} ;
    static const int errorlist_len = sizeof(errorlist) / 
                                      sizeof(*errorlist) ;
    int error_count = 0  ;

    sCharStack expected_stack = { {0},0 } ;
    int curpos = 0 ;

    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        char current_char = text[i] ;

        // Maintain cursor position
        curpos = current_char == '\n' ? 0 : curpos + 1 ;

        // Ouput content
        printf( "%c", current_char ) ;

        // Check for open bracket...
        bool open = false ;
        for( int b = 0; !open && b < bracket_type_count; b++ )
        {
            if( current_char == brackets[b].open )
            {
                open = true ;

                // Push expected closing character
                push_char( &expected_stack, brackets[b].close ) ;
            }
        }

        // Check for close bracket
        bool close = false ;
        for( int b = 0; !close && b < bracket_type_count; b++ )
        {
            if( current_char == brackets[b].close )
            {
                close = true ;

                // Check for mismatch
                char expected_char = pop_char( &expected_stack ) ;
                if( expected_char != brackets[b].close )
                {
                    //printf( "\n%*c\'%c\' expected\n", curpos - 2, ' ', expected_char ) ;
                    if( error_count < errorlist_len )
                    {
                        errorlist[error_count].expected = expected_char ;
                        errorlist[error_count].curpos = curpos ;
                        error_count++ ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Print errors after newline
        if( current_char == '\n' )
        {
            for( int e = 0; e < error_count; e++ )
            {
                printf( "%*c\'%c\' expected\n", errorlist[e].curpos - 2, ' ',  errorlist[e].expected ) ;
            }
            error_count = 0 ;
        }
    }

    // Check for unterminated brackets
    if( expected_stack.index != 0 )
    {
        printf( "\n\'%c\' expected\n", (char)pop_char( &expected_stack) ) ;
    }
}
```

Again with the test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc , char**argv]
                             ')' expected
{
    printf("this is my program\n"};
                                ')' expected
    return 0;
}
```

See now how the semi-colon at the end of the `printf()` statment is now on the same line before the error message.

Note that I have added a `length` parameter - your code attempts to write `EOF` to the `char` array and check for that - `EOF` is however an `int` not a `char` - the code may not behave as expected or the same on all platforms.

Further improvements for handling rule (2):

```
                if( errorlist[e].expected < 0 )
                {
                    printf( "%*c\^ unexpected\n", errorlist[e].curpos - 2, ' ') ;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf( "%*c\'%c\' expected\n", errorlist[e].curpos - 2, ' ',  errorlist[e].expected ) ;
                }
```

Also it is not possible for `%*c` to output zero characters (apparently) so if the error is in the first column, it will be indicated on the second column.  You could handle that by outputting spaces in a loop instead.  I'll leave that to you.

For a more robust and complete "bracket check" you might have to encode some language semantics for example to ignore delimiters that occur in literal strings or comments for example.

To load a file passed on the command line to a buffer in order to bracket-check it, I suggest the following:

```
int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    char txt[300] = {0} ;

    FILE* fp = fopen( argv[1], "rt" ) ;
    if( fp != NULL )
    { 
        int length = fread( txt, 1, sizeof(txt), fp ) ;
        brcheck( txt, length ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Your `readfile()` function is overcomplex and unsafe (no buffer overrun protection).  Moreover there is little need to use `malloc()` if you are allocating a fixed size array as small as 300 bytes.  You might want to determine the actual length of the file and allocate enough to load the whole file, but that is perhaps a different issue.  Note also that opening in *text* mode will correctly handle CR+LF line ends in Windows text files.

Comment: Mr . Clifford the whole point was reading from a text file and storing the contents on a variable and pass that variable to bracket check ? Can you do that ??? I really  appreciate your efforts !

Comment: @FizzaHoseni :  The reading from a file is not the hard part - you already have that.  I used a literal text string to make things easier _for me_ in testing the code.  In your case simply return the `int` `length` from `readfile()` rather than `txt`, then call `brcheck()` just as I have.  The extraneous EOF or NUL you are writing or `txt` can be dealt with, by returning `length - 1` or by checking for it before writing it.

Comment: @FizzaHoseni : Can I also advise that you 1) habitually comment your code as you write it or even _before_ you write it - having to explain it to yourself often helps.  2) Use a debugger for test and development - stepping through your code helps you understand how your code works, not just how it _does not_. 3) If you find your self repeating code that differs only parametrically - write a function to encapsulate it. Your code has a lot of repetition of blocks that differ only in the bracket delimiter pair used.  Get it right once and reuse, rather than having to get it right every time.

Comment: @FizzaHoseni ... also by commenting your code you are explaining it to other readers which makes it easier to ask questions on SO.

Comment: @FizzaHoseni : On reflection since your `readfile()` code was unnecessarily complex and potentially unsafe, I have added a `main()` implementation that used by `brcheck()` and reads from a file passed via the command line.